# Strange pixel displacement using responsive CSS Sprites

Tags: html, css, background-image, css-sprites, background-position

I'm working on a Knob Component that uses a Spritesheet. I need it to be responsive, relative to the screen size.

Using CSS Sprites I'm able to get the desired behaviour at maximum  Sprite size.
The problem comes when the element is scaled down. Then I get a random UP or DOWN single pixel offset on the background-position that gives like a rumbling impression.

Here you have an example Snippet to see this behaviour live:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .container{
        float:left;
        height: 10%;
        width: 20%;
    }
    .sprite{
        background: url('http://imageshack.com/a/img924/8153/hzLcvP.png') ;

        max-width: 100%; 
        background-size: 100%;
        background-position: 0 0; background-size: 100%;
        animation: play 10s steps(127) infinite;
    }
    @keyframes play {
    100% { background-position: 0 100%; background-size:100%; }
}
    
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img class="sprite" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFgAAABYAQMAAABLW6J3AAAAA1BMVEX///+nxBvIAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAABJJREFUeNpjYBgFo2AUjALsAAAEIAABfMHvuAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Note that I based my responsive beahaviour on this site: http://responsive-css.spritegen.com/

Additionally, here you have a  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ox3d6aze)

I've also tried other approaches like working in absolute pixel units, and then resizing using functions like:

```
zoom:0.5;
-moz-transform:scale(0.5);
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
```

And the same problem happens when the Scaling factor is not an exact divisor:
For example:

0.5, 0.75, 0.2 WORKS

0.3, 0.7, 0.8 OFFSET PROBLEM

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I understood that you want to make this responsive and here is my answer:

try putting that in the iframe in the following code.

```css
  * {
      padding: 0px;
      border: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
  }
  html {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
  }
  body {
      width: 100vw;
      background-color: rgb(19, 19, 19);
  }
  div#mainContainer {
      margin: calc(50vh - 50vw) 0px;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vw;
      background-color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
      z-index: 1;
  }
  iframe {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
  }
  @media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
      div#mainContainer {
          margin: 0px calc(50vw - 50vh);
          width: 100vh;
          height: 100vh;
      }
  }
```

```html
<body>
<div id="mainContainer">
    <iframe src="./iframe.html">
    </iframe>
</div>
</body>
```

And this is iframe.html

```css
* {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container{
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.sprite{
    background: url('http://imageshack.com/a/img924/8153/hzLcvP.png') ;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: 0 0; background-size: 100%;
    animation: play 10s steps(127) infinite;
}
@keyframes play {
  100% { background-position: 0 100%; background-size:100%; }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <img class="sprite" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFgAAABYAQMAAABLW6J3AAAAA1BMVEX///+nxBvIAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAABJJREFUeNpjYBgFo2AUjALsAAAEIAABfMHvuAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```